# ConnectionString from appsettings.json in Data Tier with Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have a new application that I am building on ASP.NET Core with Entity Framework Core. The application has a UI, model, business, and data tier. In previous versions of ASP.NET, you could set the connection string in the web.config and it would be available in referenced tiers by default. This does not appear to be the same case in ASP.NET Core with appsettings.json (or other config options)? Any idea on how this is accomplished? I have the dbcontext configured in the data layer, but I am current hard-coding the connection string.

All examples I have see out there has the dbcontext configured in the UI layer in startup.cs. This is what I am trying to avoid.

The question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36831774/arranging-dotnet-core-app-for-3-tiers-with-data-access-layer) got off topic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can easily add an extension method of IServiceCollection into your business/services layer and use it to register its own dependencies. Then in the startup you just call the method on the service layer without having any reference to EntityFramework in your web app.

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;

namespace your.service.layer
{
    public static class MyServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddMyServiceDependencies(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString)
        {
             services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<YourDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString)
                   .UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider)
                   );
             return services;
        }
    }

}
```

Startup:

```cs
using your.service.layer;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("EntityFrameworkConnectionString");
    services.AddMyServiceDependencies(connectionString);
}
```

Now your web app only needs a reference to your business/service layer and it is not directly dependent on EntityFramework.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Somehow I getting error. Not all code path return value in AddMyServiceDependencies

Comment: if the method is not a void ie if it is an IServiceCollection thenthe method needs to return the services object that is passed into it, that way these methods can be chained together in a fluent pattern

Comment: I've updated my answer as I had not returned in the example method

Comment: @JoeAudette How can I contact you? Maybe I can offer you small job to help me setup MVC 6 N-Tier architecture ?

Comment: @DaniilT. I'm not looking for work right now, if you want an example of tiered application in asp.net core have a look at my cloudscribe project https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe

Comment: @JoeAudette Thank you very much!

Comment: @JoeAudette and where is `appsettings.json` located? In the service layer project?

Comment: @Konrad appsettings.json is in the main web app, the services would be pulled in as nugets or class library project references. you wire up dependencies in the main web app and they get injected in any layer where they are needed.

Comment: @JoeAudette in your cloudscribe project you have design time factory connection string hardcoded, shouldn't it be shared? That is, design time factory should read from `appsettings.json`?

Comment: @Konrad design time factory is only used to generate migrations and doesn't need a valid connection string, the sample connection string works fine for this purpose. one exception is the pomelo mysql provider does need a valid connection string so I paste one in when I gen migrations for mysql then back it out.

Comment: @JoeAudette what about `update-database` ? I think it needs valid connection string.

Comment: @JoeAudette what do you think about idea of having global settings file shared between projects, stored somewhere in the root directory near `sln` file?

Comment: @Konradwe are not really supposed to chat here. I have a gitter for more casual chat https://gitter.im/joeaudette/cloudscribe

Comment: @JoeAudette I mean you still have to provide valid connection string in two places. There's a duplication. The string has to be valid for `update-database` command to work.

Comment: @Konrad honestly I don't use the update-database command. My app has code in  Program.cs that applies any new migrations at application startup time.