# Entity Framework Core migration - connection string

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm having a problem to handle the DB connection string in conjunction with migrations.
I have 2 projects:

- Domain
- Application

The `DbContext` is in the Domain project, so this is the project I run migrations against.
The migrations concept enforces me to implement `OnConfiguring` in my `DbContext` and therein specify the database provider, eg:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
{
    builder.UseSqlServer("<connection string>");
}
```

My problem is that I don't want to use a hard coded connection string, for obvious reasons, and I cannot use ConfigurationManager to read it from the config file since the config file is in the application project.

Answer (score 16):

All the examples I've seen involve either hard-coding the connection string or putting it in my ASP.NET Core application's settings files.

If you aren't using ASP.NET Core, or maybe, I don't know, don't want to have your local environment's database details committed to source control, you can try using a temporary environment variable.

First, implement `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` like this (note that `IDbContextFactory` is now deprecated):

```
public class AppContextFactory: IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<AppContext>
{
    public AppContextFactory()
    {
        // A parameter-less constructor is required by the EF Core CLI tools.
    }

    public AppContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EFCORETOOLSDB");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The connection string was not set " +
            "in the 'EFCORETOOLSDB' environment variable.");

         var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppContext>()
            .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
            .Options;
        return new AppContext(options);
    }
}
```

Then, you can include the environment variable when you call `Update-Database`, or any of the other EF Core tools:

```
$env:EFCORETOOLSDB = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=ApplicationDb;Integrated Security=True"; Update-Database
```

Comment: To set (include) the environment variable through the PM console see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47452555/5454565)

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I do it, without a lot of extra code or craziness.

Project Structure:

- AspNetCoreProject.Web
- AspNetCoreProject.Data <-- DbContext here

My DbContext is set up with the constructor that allows you to inject the DbContextOptions

***AspNetCoreProject.Data***

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

In your application or web application, you set up your `ConfigureServices` normally.

***AspNetCoreProject.Web / Startup.cs / ConfigureServices()***

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => 
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("connection"))
```

Now, what about migrations? Well, I "trick" the Visual Studio UI into working as expected.

- First, make sure your application (`AspNetCoreProject.Web` project with `Startup.cs`) is the [start up project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/0s590bew(v=vs.100)).
- Second, open up your Nuget Package Manager Console. At the top of the Nuget PM> Console, there's a dropdown for *'Set Default Project'*, point this to your `AspNetCoreProject.Data` or project with the `DbContext` class.
- Run your [migration commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db?tabs=visual-studio#create-the-database) normally.  `add-migration init` then `update-database`

Comment: Does this mean the dotnet ef migration will inspect the Startup.cs and figure out the connection string there?

Comment: Not precisely, but I'm not smart enough on what's going on under the hood to answer that question.  It does work though.

Comment: Yes, it actually does. I checked it by simply putting `Console.WriteLine($">> CONNECTION STRING: '{connectionString}'.");` in the `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method of the `Startup` class and this line was printed in the _PM Console_.

Comment: I didn't want to reference my data layer DBContext class in my presentation layer so I combined this with another Stack answer which allowed me to offload services.AddDbContext to my business layer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38356990/connectionstring-from-appsettings-json-in-data-tier-with-entity-framework-core

Comment: Just doesn't work.  Connection String is still null when running 'add-migration'

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your DbContext class has a constructor that accepts a parameter of type DbContextOptions, the dotnet ef commands have native support for this scenario - requiring no code changes nor additional configuration. Just use the "--startup-project" and "--project" parameters when creating and running migrations.

For example, let's say you have a "Application" project with your configuration and a separate project called "Domain" where the DbContext is implemented.

Context:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Startup:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => 
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("connection"))
```

CLI command:

```
dotnet ef database update --startup-project Application --project Domain
```

Comment: Thank you - this is by far the cleanest solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

We've had a same issue and there is a solution. :)

You have to implement [IDbContextFactory<TContext>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh506876(v=vs.113).aspx)
When doing so you can read the connectionstrings from your appsettings.json. You can also use Add-Migration without errors, because overwriting `OnConfigure()` is obsolete then.

Sample implementation:

```
public class DomainContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<DomainContext>
{
    public string BasePath { get; protected set; }

    public DomainContext Create()
    {
        var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

        var basePath = AppContext.BaseDirectory;

        return Create(basePath, environmentName);
    }

    public DomainContext Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)
        => Create(options.ContentRootPath, options.EnvironmentName);

    private DomainContext Create(string basePath, string environmentName)
    {
        BasePath = basePath;
        var configuration = Configuration(basePath, environmentName);
        var connectionString = ConnectionString(configuration.Build());
        return Create(connectionString);
    }

    private DomainContext Create(string connectionString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(connectionString)} is null or empty", nameof(connectionString));
        }
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DomainContext>();
        return Configure(connectionString, optionsBuilder);
    }

    protected virtual IConfigurationBuilder Configuration(string basePath, string environmentName)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(basePath)
            .AddJsonFile("constr.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"constr.{environmentName}.json", true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        return builder;
    }

    protected virtual string ConnectionString(IConfigurationRoot configuration)
    {
        string connectionString = configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
        return connectionString;
    }

    protected virtual DomainContext Configure(string connectionString, DbContextOptionsBuilder<DomainContext> builder)
    {
        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, opt => opt.UseRowNumberForPaging());

        DomainContext db = new DomainContext(builder.Options);
        return db;
    }


    DomainContext IDbContextFactory<DomainContext>.Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)
        => Create(options.ContentRootPath, options.EnvironmentName);
}
```

How we use it:

```
    public override IServiceResult<IList<Datei>> LoadAllData()
    {
        using (var db = this.DomainContextFactory.Create())
        {
            var files = db.Datei
                .ToListAsync<Datei>();

            return new ServiceResult<IList<Datei>>(files.Result, files.Result.Count);
        }
    }
```

sample config

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Put your connectionstring here"
  }
}
```

Comment: This works fine as long as you are fine with it working anterior to your IoC framework. You essentially have to maintain the code for resolving the connection string to use for both your IoC and these factories independently. Since you can't inject anything like a connection string provider, or the string itself, into your IDbContextFactory, you have to embed the connection string resolution code in the factory. Copy this ad infinitum, and you have a maintenance nightmare. This lack of a means of injection seems like a massive oversight by the EF team. Surely there is a better way.

Comment: @crush Yeah that's right. There's a new way in doing this which avoids this code. You just have to have the Connectionstring in your appsettings.json and then in your specialized environment *.json files. And in your ConfigureServices you just can use `options.UseSqlServer(this.configuration.GetconnectionString("NameFromJson"));`

Answer (score 1):

I was using OnConfiguring below with configured in Windows environment variable `MsSql.ConnectionString` and command for initial ef migration creation started to work: `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate`

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MsSql.ConnectionString");
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
        throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("Sql server connection string configuration required");
    
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        optionsBuilder
            .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
            .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
    }
}
```

To configure environment variable:

1. use `Win + R` hotkeys kombination to open `Run` command window
2. Type `systempropertiesadvanced` and hit Enter
3. On `Advanced` tab click `Environment Variables`
4. Click `New...` button
5. In `Variable name` field type `MsSql.ConnectionString`
6. In `Variable value` field type your connection string value

Make sure console(and any program that starts console) is restarted after new variable addition and before running `dotnet ef` related commands

Comment: https://www.benday.com/2017/02/17/ef-core-migrations-without-hard-coding-a-connection-string-using-idbcontextfactory/

Answer (score 0):

I have my DBContext in my console app and was using a ctor with few parameters (such as connection string etc), since EF Core Migrations was using the default parameter less ctor and hence the connection string wasn't being populated I had the migrations failing.

Just added code to get the connection string from ConfigurationBuilder within my default ctor to by pass this.

Was only playing around with console app and EF Core so this works for me for now.